# What is subclassing?

Tags: java, xml, clone, subclassing

I am new to java and I am trying to create an XML document and clone a specific node (minus the textnode) of this document over and over again.  Someone answered me and said that I should subclass the node and override the cloning. So my question is **what is sub-classing?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Charlie Martin has explained what subclassing means.

However, it is not clear that you've been given good advice.  If you are creating the XML document by assembling a DOM in memory, a better approach would be to create a helper class with static methods that perform the sequence of DOM node operations that you need to do.

Answer (score 22):

Subclassing means to define a new class that has the properties of an old class (the "superclass") with some changes.

In this case, your original responder is saying something like this:

Say you have a base class `Base` which has a method `getTwo` like so:

```
class Base {
   public int getTwo(){ return 2;}
}
```

You decide you want a new class that still have a method `getTwo` but that returns the *string* "two" instead of the number 2.  You could define it as

```
class Subclass extends Base {
   public String getTwo() { return "two"; }
}
```

We say `Subclass` is a subclass of -- or more commonly, "is a kind of" -- `Base`.

Beyond that, you'd be best off to read a book on object-oriented programming with Java.  I'm fond of [*Thinking in Java*](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/), which has the added advantage that it's available freely on line.

Answer (score 0):

In short Answer : A Superclass can be Subclassed - That means for a specific class we can find/create a subclass that extend it.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass represents `is a` relationship in Object-Oriented Programming (Inheritance).

For example
The **Circle** `is a` **Shap**.
So we can say:
The **Circle class** is a subclass of **Shape class**.