# Adding meta-information/metadata to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to add some meta-information/metadata to a pandas DataFrame?

For example, the instrument's name used to measure the data, the instrument responsible, etc.

*One workaround would be to create a column with that information, but it seems wasteful to store a single piece of information in every row!*

Comment: Please note the @ryanjdillon answer (currently buried near the bottom) which mentions the updated experimental attribute 'attrs' which seems like a start, maybe

Comment: You can register custom accessors: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#extending-register-accessors

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Sure, like most Python objects, you can attach new attributes to a `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([])
df.instrument_name = 'Binky'
```

Note, however, that while you can attach attributes to a DataFrame, operations performed on the DataFrame (such as `groupby`, `pivot`, `join`, `assign` or `loc` to name just a few) may return a new DataFrame *without* the metadata attached. Pandas does not yet have a robust method of *propagating* [metadata attached to DataFrames](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2485).

Preserving the metadata *in a file* is possible. You can find an example of how to store metadata in an HDF5 file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29130146/190597).

Comment: +1 for you choice of instrument name! Do you have any experience trying to dump these extra attributes into HDFStore?

Comment: @DanAllan: If `store = pd.HDFStore(...)`, then attributes can be stored with `store.root._v_attrs.key = value`.

Comment: To anyone else who might use this: the docs have added a section on this. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/cookbook.html#hdfstore

Comment: The [cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/cookbook.html#hdfstore) or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820071/storing-pandas-objects-along-with-regular-python-objects-in-hdf5) do not explain how to automatically add all attributes that you added to the `DataFrame` to the `HDFStore`, though.

Comment: [For posterity, this is will not be maintained during pickling in v0.18.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31727333/get-the-name-of-the-dataframe-python/31727504#comment70185470_31727504).

Comment: In pandas 0.23.1, creating a new attribute by assigning a dictionary, list, or tuple gives a warning (i.e. `df = pd.DataFrame(); df.meta = {}` produces `UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access`).  (No warning is given if the attribute has already been created as in `df = pd.DataFrame(); df.meta = ''; df.meta = {}`).

Comment: updated cookbook link: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#hdfstore-where-string-comparison

Comment: Most surprisingly, `df.copy()` does not retain custom attributes either.

Comment: There is currently an experimental attribute `.attrs` which is supposed to do this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html#metadata

Answer (score 80):

As of pandas 1.0, possibly earlier, there is now a `Dataframe.attrs` property. It is experimental, but this is probably what you'll want in the future.
For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([])
df.attrs['instrument_name'] = 'Binky'
```

Find it in the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.attrs.html).

Trying this out with `to_parquet` and then `from_parquet`, it doesn't seem to persist, so be sure you check that out with your use case.

Comment: This is interesting and does seem to persist for copy/loc/iloc, but not for groupby.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but maybe show an example of how to use it?  The documentation is basically nothing, but just from playing around with it I can see that it is initialized as an empty dictionary and it seems to be set up so that it has to be a dictionary although of course one could nest a  list inside it, for example.

Comment: You may find this [Stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122674/how-to-write-parquet-metadata-with-pyarrow) useful as it demonstrates how to add custom metadata to parquet files if required

Comment: @rdmolony That's great. I think using a `dataclass` for the metadata and then subclassing `DataFrame` to have a method doing the load/dumping as in the post you shared could be a nice solution.

Comment: This is nice. In contrast to the accepted answer, this does preserve attributes after saving and loading from pickle!

Comment: It is not persistent when stored via `to_feather()`.

Comment: This is the solution if you want the meta data to be saved when do `df.to_pickle`

Comment: This method works with `to_parquet` and `read_parquet` in pandas 2.2.0

Comment: @plx good to hear! I'll updat my answer once I've had time to verify that.

Answer (score 14):

Not really. Although you could add attributes containing metadata to the DataFrame class as @unutbu mentions, many DataFrame methods return a new DataFrame, so your meta data would be lost. If you need to manipulate your dataframe, then the best option would be to wrap your metadata and DataFrame in another class. See this discussion on GitHub: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2485

There is currently an open [pull request](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/2695) to add a MetaDataFrame object, which would support metadata better.

Answer (score 14):

Just ran into this issue myself. As of pandas 0.13, DataFrames have a _metadata attribute on them that does persist through functions that return new DataFrames. Also seems to survive serialization just fine (I've only tried json, but I imagine hdf is covered as well).

Comment: `_metadata` is not part of the public API, so I would strongly recommend against relying on this functionality.

Comment: @Stephan can you elaborate on that please? Why is it important to be a part of the public API? Is your statement also true for version 0.15?

Comment: @Stephan Sorry, I found an answer of yours elaborating on this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28054711. But is that still true today? Are there no better alternatives than to build a wrapper?

Comment: @TomCho yes, that answer is still true today. You might take a look at xray (http://github.com/xray/xray) for one alternative example of a labeled array that supports metadata, especially if you have multi-dimensional data (`.attrs` is part of the xray API)

Comment: `_metadata` is actually a class attribute, not an instance attribute. So new `DataFrame` instances inherit from previous ones, as long as the module stays loaded. Do not use `_metadata` for anything. +1 for `xarray`!

Comment: _metadata -- an unsupported feature that saved my day! Thank you.

Comment: `_metadata` _is_ part of the documented API (despite the underscore), and has been for at least five years, see pandas commit 134f1775. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#define-original-properties While it's true that `_metadata` is a class attribute, it is used to enable instance attributes.

Answer (score 11):

The top answer of attaching arbitrary attributes to the DataFrame object is good, but if you use a dictionary, list, or tuple, it will emit an error of "Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name". The following solution works for storing arbitrary attributes.

```
from types import SimpleNamespace
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.meta = SimpleNamespace()
df.meta.foo = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Also, if you want this to persist across copies of your dataframe, you need to do `pd.DataFrame._metadata += ["meta"]` . Note that this part is a attribute of Pandas, not an attribute of your specific dataframe

Comment: This approach won't work anymore as `df.meta` triggers a warning that Pandas does not allow new columns to be generated this way.

Comment: @anishtain4, I just tested it with Pandas 25.1 (released ~2 weeks ago) and this code still works for me. That warning is not triggered since `df.meta` is a SimpleNamespace. Pandas will not try and build a column from it.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by @choldgraf I have found [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) to be an excellent tool for attaching metadata when comparing data and plotting results between several dataframes.

In my work, we are often comparing the results of several firmware revisions and different test scenarios, adding this information is as simple as this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(meaningless_test)
metadata = {'fw': foo, 'test_name': bar, 'scenario': sc_01}
ds = xr.Dataset.from_dataframe(df)
ds.attrs = metadata
```

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in other answers and comments, `_metadata` is not a part of public API, so it's definitely not a good idea to use it in a production environment. But you still may want to use it in a research prototyping and replace it if it stops working. And right now it works with `groupby`/`apply`, which is helpful. This is an example (which I couldn't find in other answers):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 2, 3, 3], columns=['val']) 
df.my_attribute = "my_value"
df._metadata.append('my_attribute')
df.groupby('val').apply(lambda group: group.my_attribute)
```

Output:

```
val
1    my_value
2    my_value
3    my_value
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 5):

Referring to the section *[Define original properties](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#define-original-properties)*<sup>(of the *[official Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable)*)</sup> and if [subclassing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072780/what-is-subclassing) from [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) is an option, note that:

> To let original data structures have additional properties, you should let `pandas` know what properties are added.

Thus, something you can do - *where the name `MetaedDataFrame` is arbitrarily chosen* - is

```
class MetaedDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    """s/e."""
    _metadata = ['instrument_name']

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return self.__class__

    # Define the following if providing attribute(s) at instantiation
    # is a requirement, otherwise, if YAGNI, don't.
    def __init__(
        self, *args, instrument_name: str = None, **kwargs
    ):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.instrument_name = instrument_name
```

And then instantiate your dataframe with your (`_metadata`-prespecified) attribute(s)

```
>>> mdf = MetaedDataFrame(instrument_name='Binky')
>>> mdf.instrument_name
'Binky'
```

Or even after instantiation

```
>>> mdf = MetaedDataFrame()
>>> mdf.instrument_name = 'Binky'
'Binky'
```

Without any kind of warning (as of 2021/06/15): [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) and [`~.copy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) work like a charm. Also, such approach allows to enrich your API, e.g. by adding some `instrument_name`-based members to `MetaedDataFrame`, such as [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties) (or methods):

```
    [...]
    
    @property
    def lower_instrument_name(self) -> str:
        if self.instrument_name is not None:
            return self.instrument_name.lower()

    [...]
```

```
>>> mdf.lower_instrument_name
'binky'
```

... *but this is rather beyond the scope of this question* ...

Answer (score 4):

Coming pretty late to this, I thought this might be helpful if you need metadata to persist over I/O. There's a relatively new package called [h5io](https://github.com/h5io/h5io) that I've been using to accomplish this.

It should let you do a quick read/write from HDF5 for a few common formats, one of them being a dataframe. So you can, for example, put a dataframe in a dictionary and include metadata as fields in the dictionary. E.g.:

```
save_dict = dict(data=my_df, name='chris', record_date='1/1/2016')
h5io.write_hdf5('path/to/file.hdf5', save_dict)
in_data = h5io.read_hdf5('path/to/file.hdf5')
df = in_data['data']
name = in_data['name']
etc...
```

Another option would be to look into a project like [xray](https://github.com/pydata/xarray), which is more complex in some ways, but I think it does let you use metadata and is pretty easy to convert to a DataFrame.

Answer (score 4):

I have been looking for a solution and found that pandas frame has the property `attrs`

```
pd.DataFrame().attrs.update({'your_attribute' : 'value'})
frame.attrs['your_attribute']
```

This attribute will always stick to your frame whenever you pass it!

Comment: Note that attrs is experimental and may change without warning, but this is a very simple solution. I wonder if attrs transfers to new dataframes.

Comment: Unfortunately, attrs aren't copied to new dataframes :(

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue and used a workaround of creating a new, smaller DF from a dictionary with the metadata:

```
    meta = {"name": "Sample Dataframe", "Created": "19/07/2019"}
    dfMeta = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(meta, orient='index')
```

This dfMeta can then be saved alongside your original DF in pickle etc

See [Saving and loading multiple objects in pickle file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716812/saving-and-loading-multiple-objects-in-pickle-file) (Lutz's answer) for excellent answer on saving and retrieving multiple dataframes using pickle

Comment: Yep, you can also save the metadata file in json if it is just a dictionary, rather than casting to a pandas dataframe and then save the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Adding raw attributes with pandas (e.g. `df.my_metadata = "source.csv"`) is *not* a good idea.

Even on the latest version (1.2.4 on python 3.8), doing this will randomly cause segfaults when doing very simple operations with things like `read_csv`. It will be hard to debug, because `read_csv` will work fine, but later on (seemingly at random) you will find that the dataframe has been freed from memory.

It seems cpython extensions involved with pandas seem to make very explicit assumptions about the data layout of the dataframe.

`attrs` is the only safe way to use metadata properties currently:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.attrs.html

e.g.

```
df.attrs.update({'my_metadata' : "source.csv"})
```

How attrs should behave in all scenarios is not fully fleshed out. You can help provide feedback on the expected behaviors of `attrs` in this issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28283

Answer (score 1):

For those looking to store the datafram in an HDFStore, according to [pandas.pydata.org](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/cookbook.html), the recommended approach is:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(keys=['a', 'b', 'c'], values=['1', '2', '3']))
df.to_hdf('/tmp/temp_df.h5', key='temp_df')
store = pd.HDFStore('/tmp/temp_df.h5') 
store.get_storer('temp_df').attrs.attr_key = 'attr_value'
store.close()
```