# Does Pandas have something corresponding to Stata's "label" for column names?

Tags: pandas

In Stata you can have a variable e.g "BEH_BEHS1", with a corresponding description that is more verbose (its label) e.g "Behörighetsgivande bakgrund: studiekod del 1"

Is this possible to do in Pandas?

Thanks

Comment: Probably you can use MultiIndex instead of Index as your column.

Comment: This is not supported at the moment, this (extended labels for column names) as well as dataframe metadata, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786397/how-to-add-meta-data-to-pandas-dataframe. I also don't think MultiIndex is really suited for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not supported. For the time being you should use a dictionary which maps from the short form to the description.