# pandas.read_sas can load SAS columns labels

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to load a SAS7BDAT file into a pandas dataframe, and then into a database.

I understand that [pandas.read_sas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sas.html) allows loading a SAS7BDAT, but I'd also like to retrieve the SAS column labels and also store this in the database. (Note -- this is different to the column name and is usually a long text description of the column).

Is it possible to load the SAS text label for each column with Pandas?

Comment: AFAIK - pandas does not maintain a counterpart to *column labels*. There are discussions (see [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2485) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688306/adding-meta-information-metadata-to-pandas-dataframe)) of storing metadata in dataframes but now only remain with extensions like hdf5 and pytables.

Answer (score -1):

I achieved this by using SAS7BDAT class instead of Dataframe and when I inspected the columns, I was able to see labels as well

```
with SAS7BDAT('xxx.sas7bdat',encoding='latin-1') as sas:
for row in sas:
```

sas-> columns will have name as well as label

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example? I cannot find a publicly exposed `SAS7BDAT` class in pandas.

Comment: I think SAS7BDAT here refers to https://pypi.org/project/sas7bdat/