# Adding a timestamp to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I am doing some web scraping and storing the results in a Pandas Dataframe to subsequently output to csv. My questions is: how can I add a timestamp to the top of the Dataframe to record when I did the web scraping?

For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Fruits':['Apple','Banana','Cherry']})
```

would print:

```
  Fruits
0  Apple
1 Banana
2 Cherry
```

how can I print:

```
9/9/2017
  Fruits
0  Apple
1 Banana
2 Cherry
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688306/adding-meta-information-metadata-to-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

Setting `df.index.name`

```
df1.index.name = pd.Timestamp('9/9/2017')
df1

                     Fruits
2017-09-09 00:00:00        
0                     Apple
1                    Banana
2                    Cherry
```

---

**Option 2**

Using `df.rename_axis`:

```
df1 = df1.rename_axis(pd.Timestamp('9/9/2017'))
df1

                     Fruits
2017-09-09 00:00:00        
0                     Apple
1                    Banana
2                    Cherry
```

Comment: Yes, it works for me. However, when I convert df1 to csv using df1.to_csv, the timestamp doesn't print out. Any idea why?

Comment: @EricChoi You could instead do `df1.index.name = pd.Timestamp('9/9/2017')`. That retains it. I'm not sure why the former doesn't work.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Works very well now. Thank you very much.