# How to refer to a pandas data frame object in a function?

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe

I feel like this should be pretty straightforward but I've been getting errors.I want to create a function where I can pass in three different data frames `(temp_years_df,co2_emissions_df,energy_use_df)` and plot trends on the column 'United States' with different y-labels on the plot:

```
%pylab inline
import seaborn as sns

def US_trends(df):
  US_plot=df.T['United States'].plot()
  plt.xlabel("Year")
  if df=temp_years_df:
      plt.ylabel("Number of People Affected by Extreme Temperatures")
  elif df=co2_emissions_df:
      plt.ylabel("CO2 Emissions")
  elif df=energy_use_df:
      plt.ylabel("Energy Use")
 return US_plot

US_trends(temp_years_df)
```

But this is the error I received:

```
 if df=temp_years_df:
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried `df==temp_years_df` and it still doesn't work. Can anyone enlighten me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking for, but if you need to provide an identifier / label to assess whether to run specific logic for your input, dictionaries are one pythonic way:

```
def US_trends(dfs, label):
    df = dfs[label]
    US_plot=df.T['United States'].plot()
    plt.xlabel("Year")
    if label == 'temp_years':
        plt.ylabel("Number of People Affected by Extreme Temperatures")
    else:
        plt.ylabel("Y-label")
    return US_plot

input_dfs = {'temp_years': temp_years_df}
US_trends(input_dfs, 'temp_years')
```

Comment: No problem, feel free to accept my answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try using pandas built-in function:

```
df1.equals(df2)
```

**which returns True if both are equal, else False.**

For this specific case try:

```
if df.equals(temp_years_df):
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually set attributes to a data frame. See [Adding meta-information/metadata to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688306/adding-meta-information-metadata-to-pandas-dataframe) for more information.

```
df.df_name = "ten_years"
```

Then you can check in your function that

```
if df.df_name == "ten_years":
    doSomething
```