# Preserve original column names

Tags: python, pandas

While renaming the dataframe, I need to preserve the original names. For e.g.

```
santandar_data = pd.read_csv(r"train.csv", nrows=40000)  
santandar_data.shape  

santandar_data.original_names=santandar_data.columns

ndf=santandar_data

ndf.original_names

Index(['ID', 'var3', 'var15', 'imp_ent_var16_ult1', 'imp_op_var39_comer_ult1',
       'imp_op_var39_comer_ult3', 'imp_op_var40_comer_ult1',
       'imp_op_var40_comer_ult3', 'imp_op_var40_efect_ult1',
       'imp_op_var40_efect_ult3',
       ...
       'saldo_medio_var33_hace2', 'saldo_medio_var33_hace3',
       'saldo_medio_var33_ult1', 'saldo_medio_var33_ult3',
       'saldo_medio_var44_hace2', 'saldo_medio_var44_hace3',
       'saldo_medio_var44_ult1', 'saldo_medio_var44_ult3', 'var38', 'TARGET'],
      dtype='object', length=371)
```

The ndf dataframe object has a property original_names that works correctly. But when I use clean_names function, I do not get this functionality.

```
df=santandar_data.clean_names(case_type="upper", remove_special=True).limit_column_characters(3)
df.original_names
```

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'original_names'

The clean_names function comes from:

https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor/blob/master/janitor/functions.py

What is the best way to change this function to include original column names as a property value?

Comment: santandar_data.original_names ?

Comment: `clean_names` likely returns a *copy* of your dataframe. I believe in certain versions of Pandas attributes are not guaranteed to be copied across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly your `pyjanitor.clean_names` function returns a *copy* of an input dataframe. Copying a dataframe is [known to *not* copy arbitrary attributes assigned to an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372509/why-are-attributes-lost-after-copying-a-pandas-dataframe).

But, really, these *original* column headings don't belong to your `pd.DataFrame` instance since you can't use them directly for labeling or anything else.

My advice is to store as a separate variable. If you need to group with your dataframe, you can use a dictionary along with any additional meta data:

```
df_dct = {'df': santandar_data, 'original_names': santandar_data.columns}

df_dct['df'] = df_dct['df'].clean_names(...)
```