# Why do 'attrs' of Series in a Pandas DataFrames change to the DataFrame 'attrs' after a copy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, metadata, series

When I have a DataFrame with different `attrs` values for both the DataFrame and the Series it contains then after copying the DataFrame the original instance has the `attrs` of the DataFrame for all Series as well and the `attrs` of the Series is lost.

To be clear I'm not talking about the copied instance but about the original instance.

Here is an example of what is going on:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2])
df.attrs['a'] = 'b'
df[0].attrs['c'] = 'd'
print(f"DataFrame attrs: {df.attrs} /  Series attrs: {df[0].attrs}")
df_copy = df.copy()
print(f"DataFrame after copy attrs: {df.attrs} /  Series attrs: {df[0].attrs}")
print(f"Copied DataFrame attrs: {df_copy.attrs} /  Series attrs: {df_copy[0].attrs}")
<<<
DataFrame attrs: {'a': 'b'} /  Series attrs: {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
DataFrame after copy attrs: {'a': 'b'} /  Series attrs: {'a': 'b'}
Copied DataFrame attrs: {'a': 'b'} /  Series attrs: {'a': 'b'}
```

Also note the entry `'a': 'b'` in the Series `attrs` which is somehow copied from the DataFrame, I also find that strange, is it a bug or a feature?

I've also tried using the `_metadata` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50373364) instead but this behaves in a more or less similar way. It might use the same underlying logic:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2])
df._metadata.append('meta')
df.meta = 'a'
df[0]._metadata.append('meta')
df[0].meta = 'b'
print(f"DataFrame meta: {df.meta} /  Series meta: {df[0].meta}")
df_copy = df.copy()
print(f"DataFrame after copy meta: {df.meta} /  Series meta: {df[0].meta}")
print(f"Copied DataFrame meta: {df_copy.meta} /  Series meta: {df_copy[0].meta}")
<<<
DataFrame meta: a /  Series meta: b
DataFrame after copy meta: a /  Series meta: a
Copied DataFrame meta: a /  Series meta: a
```

I'm using Pandas version 1.4.2 and python 3.9

Comment: Related (not duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/a/29130146/15032126

Comment: And if you do `df.a = 'b'; df[0].c = 'd'`, df.a is conserved after the copy, but not df[0].c (`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'c'`).

Comment: There seems to be a bug describing the same issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/41572