# How to store custom Parquet Dataset metadata with pyarrow?

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

How do I store custom metadata to a `ParquetDataset` using pyarrow?

For example, if I create a Parquet dataset using Dask

```py
import dask
dask.datasets.timeseries().to_parquet('temp.parq')
```

I can then read it using pyarrow

```py
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
dataset = pq.ParquetDataset('temp.parq')
```

However, the same method I would use for writing metadata for a single parquet file (outlined in [How to write Parquet metadata with pyarrow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122674/how-to-write-parquet-metadata-with-pyarrow)) does not work for a `ParquetDataset`, since there is no `replace_schema_metadata` function or similar.

I think I would probably like to write a custom `_custom_metadata` file, as the metadata I'd like to store pertain to the whole dataset. I imagine the procedure would be something similar to:

```py
meta = pq.read_metadata('temp.parq/_common_metadata')
custom_metadata = { b'type': b'mydataset' }
merged_metadata = { **custom_metadata, **meta.metadata }
# TODO: Construct FileMetaData object with merged_metadata
new_meta.write_metadata_file('temp.parq/_common_metadata')
```

Comment: You can convert the Parquet schema to an Arrow schema (`dataset.schema.to_arrow_schema()`), and pass that to `pq.write_metadata`? Any metadata set in the Arrow schema will be preserved in the Parquet FileMetaData.

Comment: @joris thank you, that was indeed helpful, however, I think my original question was a bit misleading. I have now updated it with a hopefully clearer description of my problem.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility (that does not directly answer the question) is to use [dask](https://dask.org/).

```py
import dask

# Sample data
df = dask.datasets.timeseries()

df.to_parquet('test.parq', custom_metadata={'mymeta': 'myvalue'})
```

Dask does this by writing the metadata to all the files in the directory, including `_common_metadata` and `_metadata`.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

files = Path('test.parq').glob('*')

all([b'mymeta' in pq.ParquetFile(file).metadata.metadata for file in files])
# True
```