# How do I make a data frame or tibble in r from data passed using a Python API in a list or environment object?

Tags: r, reticulate, interactive-brokers

Using reticulate, I'm getting data from a Python API through Interactive Brokers.  I'd like to convert the data passed from my Python API to a data frame or a tibble, but I'm completely baffled about how to get it done.  I also cannot figure out how to recreate the data in a reprex, so I'm just providing the text as it appears on my R console.

Here's the data that gets passed to me in the openOrders object from the Python API.  It looks like this when I enter the object name at the R prompt:

```
> openOrders
[[1]]
Order(orderId=16, clientId=501, permId=115804563, action='Buy', totalQuantity=1.0)

[[2]]
Order(orderId=17, clientId=501, permId=115804564, action='SELL', totalQuantity=1.0)

[[3]]
Order(orderId=18, clientId=501, permId=115804565, action='SELL', totalQuantity=1.0)
```

When I dput openOrders and view the file, I get:

```
> dput(openOrders) %>% print()
list(<environment>, <environment>, <environment>)
[[1]]

Order(orderId=25, clientId=501, permId=306800005, action='Buy', totalQuantity=1.0)

[[2]]
Order(orderId=26, clientId=501, permId=306800006, action='SELL', totalQuantity=1.0)

[[3]]
Order(orderId=27, clientId=501, permId=306800007, action='SELL', totalQuantity=1.0)
```

R tells me the data type is a list:

```
> typeof(openOrders)
[1] "list"
```

I can access individual entries in the list:

```
> openOrders[1]
[[1]]

Order(orderId=16, clientId=501, permId=115804563, action='Buy', totalQuantity=1.0)
```

I can access individual data elements by name in the list using the following:

```
> openOrders[[1]]$orderId
[1] 16
```

When I ask for the names in the list, there are 134 of them (here's an excerpt):

```
> names(openOrders[[1]])
  [1] "account"                        "action"                         "activeStartTime"            
    ...         
[133] "volatilityType"                 "whatIf"
```

But I cannot figure out how to get the data into a data frame or tibble.  Ideally, the data frame or tibble would look like this:

```
> openOrders

    orderId clientId permId     action totalQuantity
[1] 16      501      115804563  'Buy'  1.0 
[2] 17      501      115804564  'SELL' 1.0
[3] 18      501      115804565. 'SELL' 1.0
```

I've tried the enframe function, as suggested in another post and I get:

```
> enframe(openOrders)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   name value     
  <int> <list>    
1     1 <ib_ns..O>
2     2 <ib_ns..O>
3     3 <ib_ns..O>
```

I also tried the following from another post and got the error:

```
x <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, openOrders))
Warning: Error in <Anonymous>: environments cannot be coerced to other types
```

Here's the python code:

```
from ib_insync import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Identify open orders 
def ibOpenOrders():
  orders = ib.openOrders()
  ib.sleep(0)
  return (orders)

ib = IB()
```

And here is my code in R:

```
library (reticulate)
use_python("/usr/local/bin/python3.7")
source_python("iBrokersCallsReprex.py")
openOrders <- ibOpenOrders()
```

And to get the data for dput, I set up the data in a pandas data frame on the python side before returning it to R.  I changed the python code to:

```
def ibOpenOrders():
  orders = ib.openOrders()
  ib.sleep(0)
  df = util.df(orders)
  return (df)
```

By doing that, dput returns the following:

```
structure(list(orderId = c(68, 69, 70), clientId = c(500, 500, 
500), permId = c(306801738, 306801739, 306801740), action = c("Buy", 
"SELL", "SELL"), totalQuantity = c(1, 1, 1), orderType = c("LMT", 
"LMT", "STP"), lmtPrice = c(9646.25, 9656.25, 1.79769313486232e+308
), auxPrice = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308, 
9626.25), tif = c("", "", ""), activeStartTime = c("", "", ""
), activeStopTime = c("", "", ""), ocaGroup = c("", "", ""), 
ocaType = c(0, 0, 0), orderRef = c("", "", ""), transmit = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE), parentId = c(0, 68, 68), blockOrder = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE), sweepToFill = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), displaySize =  c(0, 
0, 0), triggerMethod = c(0, 0, 0), outsideRth = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE), hidden = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), goodAfterTime = c("", 
"", ""), goodTillDate = c("", "", ""), rule80A = c("", "", 
""), allOrNone = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), minQty = c(2147483647, 
2147483647, 2147483647), percentOffset = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308),      overridePercentageConstraints = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE), trailStopPrice = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308), trailingPercent = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308), faGroup = c("", 
"", ""), faProfile = c("", "", ""), faMethod = c("", "", 
""), faPercentage = c("", "", ""), designatedLocation = c("", 
"", ""), openClose = c("O", "O", "O"), origin = c(0, 0, 0
), shortSaleSlot = c(0, 0, 0), exemptCode = c(-1, -1, -1), 
discretionaryAmt = c(0, 0, 0), eTradeOnly = c(TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE), firmQuoteOnly = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), nbboPriceCap = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308), optOutSmartRouting = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE), auctionStrategy = c(0, 0, 0), startingPrice = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308), stockRefPrice = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308), delta = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308), stockRangeLower = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308), stockRangeUpper = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308), randomizePrice = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE), randomizeSize = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), volatility = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308), volatilityType = c(2147483647, 
2147483647, 2147483647), deltaNeutralOrderType = c("", "", 
""), deltaNeutralAuxPrice = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308), deltaNeutralConId = c(0, 0, 0), deltaNeutralSettlingFirm = c("", 
"", ""), deltaNeutralClearingAccount = c("", "", ""), deltaNeutralClearingIntent = c("", 
"", ""), deltaNeutralOpenClose = c("", "", ""), deltaNeutralShortSale = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE), deltaNeutralShortSaleSlot = c(0, 0, 0), deltaNeutralDesignatedLocation = c("", 
"", ""), continuousUpdate = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), referencePriceType = c(2147483647, 
2147483647, 2147483647), basisPoints = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308), basisPointsType = c(2147483647, 
2147483647, 2147483647), scaleInitLevelSize = c(2147483647, 
2147483647, 2147483647), scaleSubsLevelSize = c(2147483647, 
2147483647, 2147483647), scalePriceIncrement = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308), scalePriceAdjustValue = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308), scalePriceAdjustInterval = c(2147483647, 
2147483647, 2147483647), scaleProfitOffset = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308), scaleAutoReset = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE), scaleInitPosition = c(2147483647, 2147483647, 
2147483647), scaleInitFillQty = c(2147483647, 2147483647, 
2147483647), scaleRandomPercent = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 
scaleTable = c("", "", ""), hedgeType = c("", "", ""), hedgeParam = c("", 
"", ""), account = c("", "", ""), settlingFirm = c("", "", 
""), clearingAccount = c("", "", ""), clearingIntent = c("", 
"", ""), algoStrategy = c("", "", ""), algoParams = list(
    list(), list(), list()), smartComboRoutingParams = list(
    list(), list(), list()), algoId = c("", "", ""), whatIf = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE), notHeld = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), solicited = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE), modelCode = c("", "", ""), orderComboLegs = list(
    list(), list(), list()), orderMiscOptions = list(list(), 
    list(), list()), referenceContractId = c(0, 0, 0), peggedChangeAmount = c(0, 
0, 0), isPeggedChangeAmountDecrease = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
), referenceChangeAmount = c(0, 0, 0), referenceExchangeId = c("", 
"", ""), adjustedOrderType = c("", "", ""), triggerPrice = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308), adjustedStopPrice = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308), adjustedStopLimitPrice = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308), adjustedTrailingAmount = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308), adjustableTrailingUnit = c(0, 
0, 0), lmtPriceOffset = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308), conditions = list(list(), list(), 
    list()), conditionsCancelOrder = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
), conditionsIgnoreRth = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), extOperator = c("", 
"", ""), softDollarTier = list(<environment>, <environment>, 
    <environment>), cashQty = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308), mifid2DecisionMaker = c("", "", ""
), mifid2DecisionAlgo = c("", "", ""), mifid2ExecutionTrader = c("", 
"", ""), mifid2ExecutionAlgo = c("", "", ""), dontUseAutoPriceForHedge = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE), isOmsContainer = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), discretionaryUpToLimitPrice = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE), autoCancelDate = c("", "", ""), filledQuantity = c(1.79769313486232e+308, 
1.79769313486232e+308, 1.79769313486232e+308), refFuturesConId = c(0, 
0, 0), autoCancelParent = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), shareholder = c("", 
"", ""), imbalanceOnly = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), routeMarketableToBbo = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE), parentPermId = c(0, 0, 0), usePriceMgmtAlgo = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
), pandas.index = <environment>)
```

On the R side, here is the structure of openOrders

```
> str(openOrders)

tibble [9 × 130] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ orderId                       : num [1:9] 140 141 142 133 134 132 148 149 150
 $ clientId                      : num [1:9] 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500
 $ permId                        : num [1:9] 1.78e+09 1.78e+09 1.78e+09 1.78e+09 1.78e+09 ...
 $ action                        : chr [1:9] "BUY" "SELL" "SELL" "SELL" ...
 $ isPeggedChangeAmountDecrease  : logi [1:9] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
  [list output truncated]
 - attr(*, "pandas.index")=RangeIndex(start=0, stop=9, step=1)
```

Here's what I get when I print the pandas data frame on the python side:

```
def ibOpenOrders():
  openOrders = ib.openOrders()
  ib.sleep(0)
  #print (openOrders.head())
  df = util.df(openOrders)
  print (df.head())
   orderId  clientId  ...  parentPermId usePriceMgmtAlgo
0       13       400  ...             0            False
1       14       400  ...             0            False
2       12       400  ...             0            False
3        7       400  ...             0            False
4        5       400  ...             0            False
```

And, here's what I get when I print just the softDollarTier attribute on the python side:

```
print (openOrders.softDollarTier)
[18 rows x 130 columns]
0     SoftDollarTier(name='', val='', displayName='')
1     SoftDollarTier(name='', val='', displayName='')
2     SoftDollarTier(name='', val='', displayName='')
3     SoftDollarTier(name='', val='', displayName='')
```

And here's what I get on the R side for that same attribute when I access it directly.

```
> head(openOrders$softDollarTier)
[[1]]
SoftDollarTier(name='', val='', displayName='')

[[2]]
SoftDollarTier(name='', val='', displayName='')

[[3]]
SoftDollarTier(name='', val='', displayName='')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you can do `dput( openOrders)` assuming only three list elements

Comment: @akrun when dput openOrders, I get the following:list(<environment>, <environment>, <environment>)

Comment: Line snippets are difficult to follow or reproduce. Please show a consolidated code block with all `library` lines. Very interested to see the Python code that builds `openOrders`.

Comment: @Parfait Do you have access to Interactive Brokers API?  If so, I have minimal code reprex that I can post.

Comment: Without the strucutre, it is not clear about your case and as it is also from python, it makes it difficult to guess

Comment: Please show how you interact with API in code.

Comment: @Parfait  I set up the data in a pandas data frame on the python side before returning it to R so I could use dput with it and added it to the post.  You can see the output from dput is quite messy with some nested lists showing up as <environment>.  Unfortunately, the dget command errors when trying to read it back.

Comment: @akrun I was able to get dput to show the structure by changing it to a pandas data frame on the python side.  See bottom of post.  The data is slightly different, because I have to do a simulation each time, but the structure is the same.

Comment: You have a big list called `openOrders`. What is the class of the object `openOrders[[1]]`? It that's a `data.frame` already, then it is simple to bind them together. Just let me know pls.

Comment: [Docs](https://github.com/erdewit/ib_insync) indicate you have to call `util()` to convert to pandas data frame. Did you run R code with this change to your Python script (i.e., latest change to get `dput`)?

Comment: @Parfait Yes, in the most recent edit of my post, you'll see the python code using the util() to convert to a pandas data frame.  And you'll also see the result of dput at the very bottom on my edited post.

Comment: @Parfait By using the python util() function, I'm able to convert to a pandas data frame which I can now convert to a tibble.  Thank you.  There is one ongoing problem.  If you look at the dput, you'll see an embedded list for softDollarTier about 13 lines from the bottom.  Any idea how to convert that data to a tibble?

Comment: @Francesco Grossetti I made an adjustment on the python side to convert the data to a pandas data frame, and now I can convert it to a tibble in r.  I'm now able to manage the data.  Thank you.

Comment: That may be a [pandas data frame meta-data attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14688398/1422451). In R, try accessing with `attributes` as `attributes(openOrders)$softDollarTier`. See my answer below for example.

Comment: @Parfait Thank you.  When I do `attributes(openOrders)$softDollarTier`, it returns NULL.  If I just want to look at the data for `openOrders$softDollarTier`, it shows me the contents of the list.

Comment: You seem to have embedded lists in your data frame columns. In Python, what does head on data frame look like using `util.df`: `openOrders = ibOpenOrders(); openOrders.head()`? Please post.

Comment: @Parfait On the python side, I need to use the `util.df()` function to change it into a pandas data frame before it recognizes `openOrders.head()`.  It shows: `orderId       clientId  ...  parent.      PermId  usePriceMgmtAlgo` and the first few lines of data for these columns.

Comment: @Parfait For the attribute softDollarTier, it prints `[18 rows x 130 columns]
0     SoftDollarTier(name='', val='', displayName='')` on the python side. And I can get the same thing on the R side using `head(openOrders$softDollarTier)`

Comment: Not familiar with that attribute. Read docs to see if you can migrate info to a data frame column in the Python function, avoiding any R side work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, as long as the Python method returns an actual Pandas data frame, `reticulate` will convert to R data frame. To demonstrate with reproducible example of various atomic types:

**Python**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

alpha = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
data_tools = ['sas', 'stata', 'spss', 'python', 'r', 'julia']

### DATA BUILD
def build_py_df():
    np.random.seed(6520)
    random_df = pd.DataFrame({'group': np.random.choice(data_tools, 500),
                              'int': np.random.randint(1, 10, 500),
                              'num': np.random.randn(500),
                              'char': [''.join(np.random.choice(list(alpha), 3)) for _ in range(500)],
                              'bool': np.random.choice([True, False], 500),
                              'date': np.random.choice(pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2019-05-31'), 500)
                             })


    return random_df

df = build_py_df()

print(df.head(10))
```

Output

```
#     group  int       num char   bool       date
# 0       r    8 -0.604529  eNR   True 2008-09-01
# 1   stata    7  0.875878  0G9   True 2004-07-13
# 2    spss    4 -0.857370  mrH  False 2017-11-29
# 3   stata    6 -2.144899  MFj   True 2003-03-03
# 4   stata    3 -0.408117  Gsh   True 2008-11-28
# 5   stata    2  1.324790  gR0   True 2004-04-15
# 6   julia    6  0.682228  jhR   True 2004-09-18
# 7  python    6 -0.993106  cqT   True 2002-03-27
# 8   julia    5 -0.346687  GfC   True 2007-04-30
# 9       r    7  0.925665  d1a   True 2006-01-01
```

**R**

```
library (reticulate)

source_python("/path/to/Python/script.py")

py_df <- build_py_df()
head(py_df, 10)
```

Output

```
#     group int        num char  bool       date
# 1       r   8 -0.6045292  eNR  TRUE 2008-09-01
# 2   stata   7  0.8758784  0G9  TRUE 2004-07-13
# 3    spss   4 -0.8573697  mrH FALSE 2017-11-29
# 4   stata   6 -2.1448990  MFj  TRUE 2003-03-03
# 5   stata   3 -0.4081175  Gsh  TRUE 2008-11-28
# 6   stata   2  1.3247895  gR0  TRUE 2004-04-15
# 7   julia   6  0.6822280  jhR  TRUE 2004-09-18
# 8  python   6 -0.9931057  cqT  TRUE 2002-03-27
# 9   julia   5 -0.3466866  GfC  TRUE 2007-04-30
# 10      r   7  0.9256647  d1a  TRUE 2006-01-01
```

For meta data

```
str(py_df)
# 'data.frame': 500 obs. of  6 variables:
#  $ group: chr  "r" "stata" "spss" "stata" ...
#  $ int  : num  8 7 4 6 3 2 6 6 5 7 ...
#  $ num  : num  -0.605 0.876 -0.857 -2.145 -0.408 ...
#  $ char : chr  "eNR" "0G9" "mrH" "MFj" ...
#  $ bool : logi  TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
#  $ date : POSIXct, format: "2008-09-01" "2004-07-13" "2017-11-29" "2003-03-03" ...
#  - attr(*, "pandas.index")=RangeIndex(start=0, stop=500, step=1)

attributes(py_df)
# $`names`
# [1] "group" "int"   "num"   "char"  "bool"  "date" 

# $class
# [1] "data.frame"

# $row.names
# [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6  
# SHOW ALL ATTRIBUTES

# $pandas.index
# RangeIndex(start=0, stop=500, step=1)

attributes(py_df)$pandas.index
# RangeIndex(start=0, stop=500, step=1)
```