# Slicing Pandas DataFrames without losing the DataFrames attributes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I like to store metadata about a dataframe by simply setting an attribute and its corresponding value, like this:
`df.foo = "bar"`
However, I've found that attributes stored like this are gone once I slice the dataframe:

```
df.foo = "bar"
df[:100].foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\project\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5465, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

I wonder if this behavior can be changed, similar to how `drop=True` or `inplace=True` change the way attributes like `df.set_index(args)` work. I didn't find anything helpful in the pandas docs.

Comment: The reason why your slice doesn't persist is probably because it creates a new dataframe without the metadata. There isn't a way to propagate that metadata though. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688306/adding-meta-information-metadata-to-pandas-dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For many operations, `pandas` returns a new object so any attributes you have defined, which aren't natively supported in the `pd.DataFrame` class will not persist.

A simple alternative is to subclass the DataFrame. You need to be sure to add the attribute to the `_metadata` else it wont persist

```
import pandas as pd

class MyDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):

    # temporary properties
    _internal_names = pd.DataFrame._internal_names
    _internal_names_set = set(_internal_names)

    # normal properties
    _metadata = ["foo"]

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return MyDataFrame
```

---

```
df = MyDataFrame({'data': range(10)})
df.foo = 'bar'

df[:100].foo
#'bar'
```

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that I'll have to use subclassing at some point which would also prove more scalable. For now, however I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60063557/16060809) answer from another thread which explains the use of df. attrs (which is a way of inheriting attributes).